# Javascript function triggers itself immediately

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom

I m trying to create DOM button object with javascript dynamically. It is being created perfectly. But my problem is if i try to assign another javascript function to one of buttons other script triggers itself when button created. `popupInsert` doesnt wait `onClick` event. Opens itself immediatly. And here is my code. How can i solve this ?

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
                                   var tr = document.createElement('Tr');
                                   tr.colSpan = '8';
                                   tableBody.appendChild(tr);


                                   for (var j=0; j<8; j++){

                                       var td = document.createElement('TD');

                                      if(j>4){
                                      var button = document.createElement('button');
                                        if(j==5)
                                            button.innerHTML = "Güncelle";
                                        else if (j==6)
                                            button.innerHTML = "Sil";
                                        else{ 
                                            button.innerHTML = "Düzenle";
                                            button.onClick = popupInsert();
                                        }
                                      button.width = '60';
                                      td.appendChild(button);
                                      tr.appendChild(td);
                                      }
                                      else if (j<5 )
                                          {

                                       td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
                                       tr.appendChild(td);
                                          }
                                   }
                                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
button.onClick = popupInsert();
```

to

```
button.onclick = popupInsert;
```

You were assigning the result of the function instead of the function and you had a typo : it's `onclick`, not `onClick`.

Comment: Side note : You should take the time to clean your indentation. You can't manage a big code when it's messy.